# Strange SSD issues, need asssistance please

Tags: ssd, bad-sectors

So for some reason my boot drive ssd just kinda seemed to have broke. I went to shut down and the system froze during shut down, had to hard restart. When I did the label on my ssd changed from patriot torch to something alone the lines of `SATAII FIRM`. Booted several live rescue cds, they can see the drive there and give me SOME information on it, but every single drive utility I try to use on it just freezes.

I've tried `diskpart`, `diskgenius`, `hard disk sentinel`, `gparted`, `HDDTune`, and many more. Tried some low level format tools to just wipe it and start over but they freeze as well. Tried scanning and repairing the MBR, same thing. Couple programs said bad superblock.

```
smartctl output:
smartctl output...

root@kali:~# smartctl --all -T permissive /dev/sda<
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-kali3-amd64] 
(local build)

Short INQUIRY response, skip product id

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Here is the `dmesg` log from when I tried to create partition table with `gparted`.
[dmesg pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kzupdznq)

[hwinfo for ssd in question](https://pastebin.com/FWbFygLA)

Comment: Your SSD is broken and needs to be replaced. Software can't fix this.

Comment: Any idea as to what could have caused it? 

I'm asking because it was working fine until I got a hard drive from a friend that I was looking into because I found an infection in the MBR of the drive. I had never come across one before so I was curious to see what I could learn from it. Could this have caused this?

Comment: Who knows. Firmware? Dead Cells? Combination of the 2. Thus is not a software (os) problem.